# Engine in Lib (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

why my engine can't be loaded?

When I startup server console show message:

```
`load_missing_constant': Expected D:/alexandre/dev/rails/project_name/lib/admin/engine.rb to define Admin::Engine (LoadError)
```

But "/lib/admin/engine.rb" exists and its contents is:

```
Admin::Engine.routes.draw do
    get '/' => "admin#index"
    get '/error' => "admin#error"

    post '/thunder' => "thunder#create", :as => "thunders"

    get '/:class' => "admin_models#index"
    get '/:class/new' => "admin_models#new"
    post '/:class' => "admin_models#create"
    get '/:class/:id' => "admin_models#show"
    get '/:class/:id/edit' => "admin_models#edit"
    put '/:class/:id' => "admin_models#update"
    delete '/:class/:id' => "admin_models#destroy"
end
```

In routes I add this line:

```
mount Admin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'admin'
```

Project specification:

- ruby 1.9.2p180
- Rails 3.2.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file "/lib/admin/engine.rb", should define the constant Admin::Engine, or more explicitely that file should define the class Admin::Engine. Here is a minimal example of the content for that file

```
module Admin
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    #isolate_namespace Admin #see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html#label-Isolated+Engine
  end
end
```

The snipped you posted before is about the routes of your engine and should therefore be placed in "config/routes.rb"

The [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.htm) and the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) are great ways to get familiar with engines. If you like books, I advise you to read [Crafting Rails Applications](http://plataformatec.com.br/crafting-rails-applications) which is a small but very dense book and talks extensively about engines (and is written by one of the most awesome rubyist : Jose Valim).

Comment: So, if snipped code should be placed in "config/routes.rb", I don't need a engine, it's right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you still need an engine because when subclassing Rails::Engine you are actually subclassing Rails::Railtie and therefore you will run the inherited callback (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7f8f554d75a4c1fe56fda1cbf39f67a0b32b5c16/railties/lib/rails/railtie.rb#L129 ) which is the way you're telling Rails to use the engine during the initialization. If you want an engine (and not a simple railtie ) it's probably because you want the engine default initialization to be run, right ?

Comment: hm, I understood.  
I was trying to mount an engine inside the '/lib'.  
Now building a gem I noticed a '/config/lib' itself.